# Give subpartition more space Ubuntu Server

Tags: server, partitioning

I'm fairly new to ubuntu server and I want to extend my partition.

I ran `sudo lsblk -o NAME,FSTYPE,SIZE,MOUNTPOINT,LABEL` and got the following result:

```
NAME                      FSTYPE       SIZE MOUNTPOINT        LABEL
loop0                     squashfs    69.8M /snap/lxd/19032   
loop1                     squashfs    69.9M /snap/lxd/19188   
loop2                     squashfs    32.3M /snap/snapd/11107 
loop3                     squashfs    55.5M /snap/core18/1988 
loop4                     squashfs    31.1M /snap/snapd/11036 
loop6                     squashfs    55.4M /snap/core18/1944 
loop7                     squashfs    31.1M                   
sda                                    2.7T                   
├─sda1                    vfat         512M /boot/efi         
├─sda2                    ext4           1G /boot             
└─sda3                    LVM2_member  2.7T                   
  └─ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv ext4         200G /                 
sr0                                   1024M
```

As you can see `sda3` has 2.7T of storage and `ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv`only uses 200G.
Is there an easy way to give `ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv` more storage?
I've read about `gparted` but this looks quite sus to me.

Comment: Why do you think gparted isn't trustworthy?

Comment: Their website looks like it's created 400 b.c. I know there are a lot of good tools that have a website like that but I just not like to trust them.

Comment: almost every website for these open source and widely trusted tools look like that. It's when a site is super fancy with bad grammar that you should be cautious.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the volume group is already defined as being 2.7TB in size, you can extend the logical volume and allocate everything with just four commands. Here’s how:

0. Open Terminal, if it’s not already open
1. Extend) the logical volume by telling the LVM that the physical partition size has changed:

   ```
   sudo pvresize /dev/sda3
   ```
2. Find the actual path of the LVM logical volume:

   ```
   sudo lvdisplay
   ```
3. Instruct the LVM to extend the logical volume to use all of the new partition size:

   ```
   sudo lvextend -l +100%FREE /dev/ubuntu--vg/ubuntu--lv
   ```

   ***Note:** Be sure to change the path to match the proper one from point 2.*
4. Resize the file system to use all of that new space:

   ```
   sudo resize2fs /dev/ubuntu--vg/ubuntu--lv
   ```

This should give you a 2.7TB `ext4`-formatted partition

Comment: Works very well. Thank you very much for the explanation